# How is $\nabla\cdot \mathbf P$ sufficient to describe the volume polarization $\mathbf P$

Tags: electrostatics, potential, polarization

I'm self-studying Panofsky and Philips' *Classical Electricity and Magnetism*. In Section 1-10, they talk about the potential due to a volume polarization $\mathbf P$ being effectively divorcing into surface and volume charge densities. They write (everything in the bracktets is I writing)

> $$
> \sigma_P=P_n,\quad \rho_P=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf P\tag{1-71}
> $$
> Note that if $\mathbf P$ does not have discontinuities, the volume charge $\rho_P=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf P$ is sufficient to describe the source [**Question 1**]; it can easily be proved that the expression for $\sigma_P$ in Eq. (1-71) will result if $\nabla\cdot \mathbf P$ becomes infinite at a boundary [**Question 2**].

**Questions:**

1. How? Giving the derivative still doesn't fix the arbitrary constant, and I don't see how it can fix the polarization at the boundaries.
2. I don't even understand this claim, let alone prove it. Any help?

Comment: I dont really see why it would have to become infinite at the boundary to give 1.71. But the trick would be Stokes's theorem (or its divergence incarnation).

Comment: I do not think that these equation determine P. Also 'descibe the source' for me does not mean it does, doesnt it?

Comment: @lalala I think that ‘describe the source’ means being able to find the potential uniquely.

Comment: Yes, the potential probably. But not the polarisaton. Basically any vector field needs at least div and curl to specify, think about a 'pure curl' field, then also sigma P vanishes (as well as rho_p)

Comment: @lalala Agreed. But what does it lead to?

Comment: I think the point of the above comment is that the text *isn't* saying that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf P$ is enough to determine $\mathbf P$; it's saying that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf P$ is enough to determine all of the bound charge in the system.

Comment: That either the book does not mean you can determine P, or that the book is wrong. (Although we should write down precisely the example P we discussed; so 3rd option is we made a mistake)